# 'Guttman yad-brush' font

Tags: fonts, hebrew, word-to-latex

I am familiar and kind of like this font, from (god forgive me) "Microsoft Word" program. It's actually a hebrew font.
An example of the font is [at this page](http://www.google.co.il/imgres?q=guttman%20yad%20brush&hl=en&biw=1503&bih=661&gbv=2&tbm=isch&tbnid=mGwwFqevflpwjM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.fontyukle.net/en/Guttman%2bYad-Brush.ttf&docid=XepYWQYhbKVuNM&imgurl=http://www.fontyukle.net/en/karakter.php%253Fid%253D37557%2526set%253D3&w=518&h=274&ei=oL3zTqieMYay8QORtcm6AQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=583&vpy=167&dur=5775&hovh=163&hovw=309&tx=138&ty=79&sig=100766837829771718865&page=1&tbnh=103&tbnw=195&start=0&ndsp=19&ved=1t:429,r:2,s:0)

I would like to know if it's possible to use it in LaTeX, and also if it's possible to use it with English letters as well (it looks kinda hand writing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look into using [XeTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX). With XeTeX, you can integrate all of your system fonts right into your document.

You would be able to use this font with the MWE below.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltxtra} % loads: fixltx2e, metalogo, xunicode, fontspec
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Guttman Yad-Brush}
\newfontfamily{\L}{Helvetica Neue}

\begin{document}
\section{Guttman Yad-Brush Testing!}
שלום, עולם

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\noindent
{\L Hello, world!}
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image: image of my MWE]

As you can see, you would not be able to use Latin characters with this font, simply because the font doesn't support Latin characters. This is independent of TeX.