# Typesetting any language, Vietnamese for example

Tags: languages

I have this document which contains Vietnamese characters, and it doesn't compile correctly:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[vietnam]{babel}
\begin{document}
        Ðàn con chung một trái tim
\end{document}
```

The characters come out as gobbledygook. I don't know how to give Latex the ability to display characters in any language. It's rather frustrating because I'm used to just typing anything I want in UTF-8.

What are the steps to enabling a language in a Latex document? For the answer, you can use my Vietnamese example.

Comment: One (simple) option is to use XeTeX. See my answers for ['Guttman yad-brush' font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39157/guttman-yad-brush-font/39161#39161) and [Problems typing in Russian (MiKTeX)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39212/problems-typing-in-russian-miktex/39213#39213). These should be able to help you. But you would of course want to use [`polyglossia`](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) instead of `babel`.

Comment: Nate Glenn: I have the same problem when I copy&paste Vietnamese text containing the capital D with horizontal bar character from the Internet using Chrome. Work around is find & replace that character with the one you type in. (I use unikey)

Comment: One thing to remember is that inputenc's UTF-8 is incomplete and I believe that "Ð" is precisely one of the characters it doesn't understand. You really should use XeTeX or LuaTeX for anything other than fairly common UTF-8.

Comment: @PLK There are *two* characters which are represented graphically by "Ð"; `inputenc` understands both, but the Vietnamese module doesn't know what to do with the Icelandic "Ð".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I copied the start of the Hanoi entry in the vietnamese Wikipedia:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnam]{babel}

\begin{document}

Hà Nội là thủ đô, đồng thời là thành phố đứng đầu Việt Nam về diện
tích tự nhiên và đứng thứ hai về diện tích đô thị sau thành phố Hồ Chí
Minh, nó cũng đứng thứ hai về dân số với 6.913.161 người.

\end{document}
```

The trick is to enable the `utf8` encoding for the package `inputenc`.

***Note*** The proper Unicode character for the capital "đê" (or "đờ") character is Đ (U+0110 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D WITH STROKE) and not the one you're using,
that is Ð (U+00D0 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ETH). They are pretty similar, but distinct. The former is used in Croatian and Vietnamese, the latter in Icelandic (and its lowercase form is ð).

---

[image]

---

In case different languages must be used, they should be declared to `babel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,vietnam]{babel}

\begin{document}

Hà Nội là thủ đô, đồng thời là thành phố đứng đầu Việt Nam về diện
tích tự nhiên và đứng thứ hai về diện tích đô thị sau thành phố Hồ Chí
Minh, nó cũng đứng thứ hai về dân số với 6.913.161 người.

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
Hanoi is the capital of Vietnam and the country's second largest city.
Its population in 2009 was estimated at 2.6 million for urban
districts, 6.5 million for the metropolitan jurisdiction.
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

For short inserts in English, `\foreignlanguage{english}{some text in English}` can be used. One can also define a personal abbreviation, such as

```
\newcommand{\EN}{\foreignlanguage{english}}
```

so to be allowed to write `\EN{some text in english}`. You can also abbreviate the environment form with

```
\newenvironment{english}
  {\begin{otherlanguage}{english}}
  {\end{otherlanguage}}
\newenvironment{english*}
  {\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}}
  {\end{otherlanguage*}}
```

See the `babel` manual for the difference between `otherlanguage` and `otherlanguage*`.

---

Alternatively, you can use XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{vietnamese}

\begin{document}

Hà Nội là thủ đô, đồng thời là thành phố đứng đầu Việt Nam về diện
tích tự nhiên và đứng thứ hai về diện tích đô thị sau thành phố Hồ Chí
Minh, nó cũng đứng thứ hai về dân số với 6.913.161 người.

\end{document}
```

which gives a correct result:

---

[image]

---

Polyglossia issues a warning about missing hyphenation patterns for Vietnamese, which should not be a problem.

For declaring other languages to Polyglossia, one should use, for instance,

```
\setotherlanguage{english}
```

Note that the same commands as in `babel` can be used with Polyglossia, but in this case the `english` environment would already be defined, so only `english*` might need to be.

Comment: Almost. When I use the character "Ð" (the lower case one is fine, though), I get this error: `! LaTeX Error: Command \DH unavailable in encoding T5.`

Comment: @NateGlenn Would you please update your minimal example?

Comment: Done. Got rid of the covington stuff as it wasn't very minimal.

Comment: @NateGlenn You should segregate the non Vietnamese parts in `otherlanguage*` environments. I'll add an example.

Comment: Can you try compiling using the text from my MWE (I just edited)? It gives me the 'encoding unavailable error' because of the Ð character.

Comment: @NateGlenn I've added a note: you're using the wrong character.

Comment: Don't know how that happened. Works great now!

Comment: (Not relevant to the question, but I would *not* recommend using `covington` independently.  Both `gb4e` and `linguex` are better linguistic example packages than `covington`.)

Answer (score 5):

Add `\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}` to the preamble. Note that this only works with LaTeX or PDFLaTeX, not with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX because of encoding issues.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam} 
\begin{document} 
Hà Nội là thủ đô, đồng thời là thành phố đứng đầu Việt Nam về diện tích tự nhiên và đứng thứ hai về diện tích đô thị sau thành phố Hồ Chí Minh, nó cũng đứng thứ hai về dân số với 6.913.161 người. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: @damvantai This doesn’t work for me, with either pdflatex, xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: @doncherry Really? It works for me. Actually before my switch to `babel`, I used this approach - it is more popular in Vietnamese LaTeX groups.

Comment: @JouleV You're right, now it works with pdflatex, but not with xelatex or lualatex. Something must've changed.

Comment: @doncherry This only works with LaTeX and PDFLaTeX, because the encoding system in Xe and LuaLaTeX is different from in PDFLaTeX. In average Vietnamese LaTeX users don't really like XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. You can read about this approach in [this paper](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-1/tb91thanh-vntex.pdf) (by Hàn Thế Thành, the author of PDFTeX - maybe that is why `vietnam` doesn't work with Xe and LuaLaTeX). In conclusion I don't understand why this answer is downvoted - if it were in a Vietnamese community it would be upvoted more than egreg's answer.

Comment: @JouleV I can only trust my past self that it actually didn't work back then, hence the downvotes, I guess (not from me though).

Comment: @doncherry The linked paper is since 2007, so it _must_ work back then. Maybe at the time of this answer, the version of `vntex` in TeX Live has some bugs.