# LaTex error : ! LaTeX Error: Command \ecircumflex unavailable in encoding T1

Tags: fonts, errors

I get a trouble in compiling LaTex. I used Texlive and Texmaker(in Xubuntu 13.04) for writing LaTex, the error says : *LaTeX Error: Command \ecircumflex unavailable in encoding T1.*

note that in window XP, with Miktex and Texmaker, the following MWE worked correctly.

Here is a minimal working example :

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountsec,sectrefs,vecarrow,envcountretsec]{svmono}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\savesymbol{hbar}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{esvect}
\begin{document}
Tiếng Việt không hiển thị được(i.e: Can not display vietnamese character correctly): $\widearc{AB}, \wideOarc{AB}$ ?
\end{document}
```

So, how can I fix this error ?

Comment: Read [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40484/8528) for more information.  The key in this case seems to be adding the appropriate call to `babel`.  I would also add a `\usepackage[T1,T5]{fontenc}` if using `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fourier` package does

```
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

so T1 becomes the default encoding. Just do

```
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
```

so the default encoding will be T5 (Vietnamese).

I find it quite strange all the font juggling you do; surely loading `type1cm` is useless. Also loading `mathptmx` and doing `\savesymbol{\hbar}` does nothing, because the Fourier fonts have their own `\hbar` symbol.

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountsec,sectrefs,vecarrow,envcountretsec]{svmono}

\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{helvet}      % Helvetica for sans serif
\usepackage{courier}     % Courier for monospaced

\usepackage{fourier}     % Utopia for the main font
\usepackage[T5]{fontenc} % restore the Vietnamese encoding

\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document}

Tiếng Việt không hiển thị được(i.e: Can not display vietnamese 
character correctly): $\widearc{AB}, \wideOarc{AB}$?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I solved this question myself, but I still do knot know what is the real mistake that led to that error :

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountsec,sectrefs,vecarrow,envcountretsec]{svmono}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\savesymbol{hbar}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{esvect}
\begin{document}
Thế bác Điển nói gì về lỗi này : $\widearc{AB}, \wideOarc{AB}$ ?
\end{document}
```

If you know where the error (of the first MWE in my question) in fact came from, please tell me. Thank so much :)